# Silverlight projects on one IIS web site

Tags: silverlight, xap

I have silverlight project and this project are deploying in IIS. But in solution I created two another SL projects with .Web projects. The problem that I cannot deploy these projects in web site (IIS). How I can do this? How I can do this xaps and dlls are visible for project?
In these two projects i have wcf services too.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple web pages and each has their own silverlight xap, you can just set in IIS the default web page to be viewed then put a navigation of some sort in the webpage (links or redirects) so you view the other web pages.